# How to make the div responsive and collapse to tabs on a small screen

Tags: html, css, tabs, responsive

I have three side by side divs and how to make them collapse into tabs on a small screen.

Basically three divs all visible on a large screen, but convert into three tabs corresponding to three tabs and only the active one is shown with a small screen size.

Comment: For us to answer this we need to see your [mcve] code, please share that with us in order that we can offer practical help rather than blind guesses that may, or may no, be entirely invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs device-small" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active col col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="home">...home...</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="profile">...profile...</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="messages">...messages...</div>
      </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
   @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .device-big {
        display: none;
        }
        .device-small {
        display: block;
        }
    }
    /* big device */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
        .device-big, .tab-content > .tab-pane {
        display: block;
        }
        .device-small {
        display: none;
        }
        .tab-content > .tab-pane {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you heard of "mobile first"?  Make the mobile device show correctly then fix the code to support bigger devices.

Comment: Also, why do you think Bootstrap is being used?